# window.location.reload() causes an Application Error on PhoneGap 1.4 / Android Honeycomb 3.2.1

Tags: android, cordova, android-3.0-honeycomb

Why does `window.location.reload() === instant_fail` on Android 3? I just get an Application Error popup with the file:///... URL of my application, and have to restart. I've tried overriding `DroidGap.onReceivedError()` but it just tries and fails to reload itself repeatedly.

Comment: How about you try use reload();

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if you still need an answer to this, but this might help someone.  I encountered the same problem with PhoneGap running on Android 3.  I solved it by replacing this line:

```
location.reload(true);
```

with this:

```
navigator.app.loadUrl('file:///android_asset/www/index.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

A device agnostic solution would be to use:

```
window.location = 'index.html';
```